# Rails: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) when calling save but passing no arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Running into a strange argument error. I get a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error when submitting a form. Logs report it's happening on the call to `if @object.save` but I'm not passing in any arguments. Here's the create method involved.

```
#venue_imports_controller.rb
def create
  @venue_import = VenueImport.new
  @file = params[:venue_import][:file]

  Rails.logger.debug "--> Trying to read csv file..."
  content = File.read(@file.tempfile)
  Rails.logger.debug "--> Loading csv contents into content column..."
  @venue_import.content = content

  if @venue_import.save
    Rails.logger.debug "--> Made it into the save "
    process_files!
    flash[:notice] = "CSV upload is being processed"
    render :new
  else
    flash[:notice] = "CSV upload could not be processed"
    render :new
  end
end


#venue_import.rb
require 'csv'

class VenueImport < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  extend ActiveModel::Naming 
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  attr_accessor :file, :saved_venues, :unsaved_venues

  def valid?
    errors.empty?
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  end


      #log output
      User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
    --> Trying to read csv file...
    --> Loading csv contents into content column...
    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

    ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0):
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:77:in `perform_validations'
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
    app/controllers/admin/venues/venue_imports_controller.rb:15:in `create'
    actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
    actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block in _run__2350649128043012098__process_action__1475487348551593386__callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_451'
    activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:326:in `around'
    activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:310:in `_callback_around_13'
    activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:214:in `_conditional_callback_around_451'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__2350649128043012098__process_action__1475487348551593386__callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
      activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'


      activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
      activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
      activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
      journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
      journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:594:in `call'
      omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
      omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
      warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
      warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
      activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
      activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
      activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__9921957878612641__call__2635867529413993280__callbacks'
      activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
      activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
      activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
      airbrake (3.1.15) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
      better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
      better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
      better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
      railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
      railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
      activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
      airbrake (3.1.15) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
      airbrake (3.1.15) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
      railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
      railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
      railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/deflater.rb:13:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
      railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
      thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
      thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
      thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:55:in `process'
      thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
      eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
      thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
      thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
      railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
      railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
      railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
      script/rails:6:in `<main>'
      script/rails:0:in `<main>'



    Started POST "/__better_errors/70352114726040/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-31 16:28:14 -0700
```

I've tried taking out the call to `process_files!` to make sure that wasn't causing any issues. No luck.

Comment: Post VenueImport model code and stack trace

Comment: Do you have any ActiveRecord callbacks (before_save, after_save, etc) in your VenueImport model where the error could be occuring?

Comment: @infused No callbacks being used in the model (now added to the original post)

Comment: @LoganSerman Also added the log output

Comment: Why are you including the ActiveModel stuff if the class already is an ActiveRecord model? Either remove `< ActiveRecord::Base` from the class definition or remove the ActiveModel includes and extends as well as the `valid?` and `persisted?` methods.

Comment: @infused I removed those lines but the same issues exist triggered by the same line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove ActiveModel and just rely on ActiveRecord. ActiveRecord already includes these modules. The reason your save is failing is because ActiveRecord uses a chain of `super` calls to validate your models when you call `save`. When you include ActiveModel on top of ActiveRecord, it messes with the inheritance chain so `super` is calling the wrong `save` method.

Comment: I removed these from the model but the same error persists from the same line (the call to `if @venue_import.save`)